# How do I use a grid to center a frame in a window?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I have created a frame containing a label and a button. When I expand the toplevel window, the frame is anchored at the top left of the window. How do I center the frame within the toplevel window? I am using the "grid" geometry manager.

```
frame .frame
ttk::label .frame.title -text "Rocket 1"
ttk::button .frame.button -text "Launch!"

grid .frame
grid .frame.title
grid .frame.button
```

[image: GUI created using Tcl/Tk]

How do I vertically and horizontally center the label and button?

Comment: With the keywords you mention in your question, I'm really surprised you didn't find the answer in the grid manual page: `grid anchor . center`

Comment: @SchelteBron Thank you. This is my first Tcl/Tk application, and the first time I am reading the Tk man pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the anchoring of the grid within its space. In your case:

```
grid anchor . center
```

Note that because you have two grids nested within each other (one in the toplevel, one in the frame) you have to think carefully about which one has the extra space. It's often instructive to set the fill color of frames to something garish (bold red, green, blue, etc) while fixing layout bugs.

To show what I mean, I've added:

```
# With apologies to people with Daltonism; pick other colours if you prefer
. configure -bg green
.frame configure -bg red
```

to your script, giving a window like this:

[image: with backgrounds set]

Now, if I do:

```
grid anchor .frame center
```

it looks identical (the grid of widgets is now centered within the red area that is shrunk-to-fit around them), but if I do:

[image: backgrounds and anchoring]

then you can see that the group of widgets on the red background (`.frame`) is now placed centrally within the green area (`.`).

Comment: FWIW, I find I don't use many `frame`s when making layouts with `grid`.